# Partial derivative of a vector field at a given point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, vector-fields

[Vector Field and associated question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90rCa.jpg)

I'm wondering how to answer parts 1-4 of this question.

My attempt goes as follows:

Taking #1 as an example, I know that $P(x,y)$ is the x-component of the vector field, and $P_x$ should be the change of position with respect to change in x, but this line of thinking leads me to conclude that (b) is the answer to (1), instead of (a).

I know that curl($F$) at this point is positive, which tells me that $Q_x-P_y>0$, but I'm not sure what to do with this information (if it's even the right direction of thinking)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show your attempts. Or else your question has a high chance to be closed.

Comment: You should edit your question and put your attempt in it.